# When are two affine varieties equal?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

Very elementary question here, but I just wanted to know when two affine varieties are considered to be equal. To give the most fundamental example I can think of. The varieties $V_1$ and $V_2$ defined by
\begin{equation*}
V_1 := \{ x \in \mathbb{R} | x = 0 \}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
V_2 := \{ x \in \mathbb{R} | x^2 = 0 \}
\end{equation*}
both consist of the same point, $x=0$. Are these varieties equal because they consist of the same point in $\mathbb{R}$, or are they unequal because they are each defined by different polynomials, $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x^2$, respectively?

Specifically, is it the *points* that define the variety, or is it the *polynomials* that define the variety?

Comment: It's the points.

Comment: In algebraic geometry, the defining equations are important and the two that you describe would be considered different, though many people will not call the latter a "variety", but a scheme. A starker example would be the variety defined by $x^2+1=0$ in $\mathbb{R}[x]$. As points, it is empty over the reals, but surely you wouldn't want to think of it as empty.